# Read cell value & entire row from a workbook & loop through multiple rows

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

1.I want to be able to read a value from a cell  from a closed workbook & place it in a variable where in each cell is of different type ( i.e. integer or character etc) .Also is it possible to read an entire row in one shot & place it in an array & use it in the program?

Algorithm :

1. Read from a closed excel file -> I want to know how to open a file & read cell data;
2. Need to read entire row from column 1  to column 200 of Frist row & need to assign it to a variable in the below fashion, but ensuring the data type is maintained ( i.e string should remain string & integer to remain as integer)

   Variable 1 equals Cell value of (A1) where A1 is a string 
   Variable 2 equals cell value of (B1) where B1 is integer 
   Varaibale 3 equals cell value of (c1) where C1 is string 
   ::
   ::
   Variable 200 equlals  cell value of (row 1 column 200) where value is string

   What is the best way to do this.
3. I should be able through 100 rows & do the step 2 each time for the corresponding rows & columns.

Can you please advise

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

To open a workbook you need to simply give the address of your workbook and assign it to a new variable and by applying the **Open** method on the object **Workbooks** you can open it:

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()
Dim FileName As String
'Assign the address of your file to the variable FileName
FileName = "\FileAddress\FileName.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open FileName
End Sub
```

Till now you have opened your desired excel workbook.

**Step 2**
Then you need to read the desired cells of your workbook.
You should assign each cell separately to a new variable. 
So you can write the code to do that for you:

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()
Dim FileName As String
'Assign the address of your file to the variable FileName
FileName = "\FileAddress\FileName.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open FileName
Dim A1 As String
A1 = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("A1")
Dim B1 As Integer
B1 = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("B1")
Dim C1 As Integer
C1 = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("C1")
'You continue until the column 200. If  there is some logic you can assign your similar variables by a for loop to an array.
End Sub
```

**Step 3**

For your problem you need to define arrays. Otherwise you cannot solve this issue.
If you need to go through 100 lines you need to define an array with the dimension of 100 for each columns. Arrays A(99) starts from A(0) to A(99) which has the dimension of 100.
For example for iterating in 3 columns for 100 rows you can write:

```
Sub IterationInRows()
Dim A(99) As String, i As Integer
Dim B(99) As Integer
Dim C(99) As String
'Continue through all your variables
For i = 0 to 99
  A(i) = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Ragne("A" & i+1)
  B(i) = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Ragne("B" & i+1)
  C(i) = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Ragne("C" & i+1)
Next i
End Sub
```

I think by combining these 3 steps you can solve your issue.

If there is a logic in your columns arrangements you can define multi-dimensional arrays and assign all the values of columns with similar data type to that array.

Let say that the **odd columns** (1, 3, 5, ..., 199) are all strings. Therefore you have 100 columns with string data type and you want to iterate in 100 rows.

So you need to define an array like A(99,99) to iterate through all of them by using two nested for loops.

So you write a code like this:

```
Sub Iteration2()
Dim A(99,49) As String, i as integer, j as integer
For i = 0 to 99
  For j = 0 to 99
    A(i,j) = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Cells(i+1,2*j+1)
  Next j
Next i 
End Sub
```

It is possible to close your workbook by code as well. However, you need to assign your workbook to an object and then you apply the method close to that object. But I think you do not need it.

Your question was a bit broad. But I hope I could help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Hey Kiran , Thank you so much for your valuable advise. It was certainly very helpful.

Comment: I want to narrow down my requirement & keep it more specific , Basically i need to read just one row having 200 cells & i want to store the value of each cell in a unique variable ( each cell may be of different datatype). I want to repeat the same thing for 99 rows. The variables which i will use to assign the cells 1 to 200 in a row will remain same just the values of those 200 variables can keep changing i.e when in loop the variables will have values from 2nd row so on & so forth till row 99. what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Basically once the variable 1 to variable 200 is populated i will do some calculation & then i wont need the values anymore i am ready to fill those variable 1 to variable 200 with next set of rows ..

Comment: It is not possible to put different data types in an array. You can do this but it will consider all of your data as variant type and therefore you cannot do the calculation on your data. If you know the sequence of your columns and how they are arranged it may be possible to do something. But what is the calculation you want to do? The only possible calculation I can imagine for 200 columns with different data type is something related to the strings. For example concatenate all the 200 columns. Therefore you do not have a problem for putting all the 200 cells in an array.

Comment: Hi Kian, I tried executing the assign statement  it was giving an error saying method or property not supported this was a point at A1 assignment.  Is there an alternative approach to assign cell value to a variable?

Comment: I am talking about step2

Comment: I replaced ' Excel File Name 'with FileName & Sheet Name with sheet1 still it dint work

Comment: Can you please advise

Comment: Considering my array is of type string & all fields in the cells are also string , I have been looking to see what is the best way to read an entire row in to a n array

Comment: Also what is the best way to read one cell value of a row in to  a variable ? the option , Dim A1 As String
A1 = Workbooks("Excel File Name").Workbooks("Sheet Name").Range("A1")  is not working unfortunately.

Comment: I am particularly trying to read this one cell value from a closed workbook

Comment: Also is there a way to define a variant variable which can have any datatype?

Comment: I will answer you in more detail later. But I have written the command incorrectly. The right command is: Workbooks("Excel File Name").Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("A1")

Comment: Sure thanks will wait for your response.Also I believed  you may have accidentally pasted the same statement again in the above comment .

Comment: No, you have used the "Workbooks" two times in your command. In the second one you should write "Worksheets" instead of "Workbooks". Look at your comment please.